# Not getting any sound from ATI HDMI

Tags: windows-7, audio, amd-radeon, playback

I am not getting any sound on LCD TV when HDMI are connected to ATI 5800 graphic card. I have checked all the volume on the Playback devices on Windows 7, I've clicked Test button on each playback device - I am not getting any sound.

What might be a problem?

I do see ATI Digital Audio (HDMI) on the Playback device

Comment: Are you using updated graphics drivers for your card?

Comment: The AMD Catalyst drivers have an option for HDMI audio. You have the option not to install these. Can you check that is it installed in your system?

Comment: @Hennes I can't remember but I do see ATI Digital Audio (HDMI)  listed on the Playback device

Answer (score 3):

I've also searched a while to find the cause for my HD5770. You must disable the other output devices in the sound options and set the TV as default device. Now it works for me.